# On a button click I want to display a toast message

Tags: java, android

I want that this message is displayed only the first three times this button is clicked and never after that even if the application is restarted, I want to know the  best way to achieve it. I plan to make a DB and enter values in that DB on button press and place my toast logic inside of an if statement. I want to know if there is a better way to do it without using a DB.

Comment: shared preference is best way.....

Answer (score 3):

If by better you mean easier then you can use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) mechanism.

The shared preferences is basically a property set that is common for your entire activity or can be used by each activity separately.

```
class Listener implements OnClickListener{
    final private SharedPreferences prefs;
    Listener(SharedPreferences prefs){
         this.prefs=prefs;
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int count = prefs.getInt("toastCount",0);
        if(count>=3) return;
        //do something else here
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("toastCount", count+1);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

and you can initiate this listnener using the `getPreferences()` or `getSharedPreferences()` methods from your activity

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I am done with it! Though am new to android, I would like if you provide me a link to a beginners tutorial on shared preference.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

also please accept my answer as the one :-)

Answer (score 1):

i think [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) is better than DB.

You just add `count(int)` in shared Prefernces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(app.getBaseContext(),"Your message", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Consider persisting your data somewhere in the memory. Trivial data like this should not go into the database. It would be a bad decision.